# How to optmize SQL query (search by criteria in history/actual versioning pattern)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have actual and history tables in PostgreSQL database.

```
create table actual (id int, name text, version int);
create table history (id int, name text, version int, actual_id int);
```

When a record changes it is copied to the history table and the actual version increments. Rows cannot be deleted.

E.g. if we have 3 records A1, B1, C1 (1 is the version number) and change B's name, then the actual table will contain A1, B2, C1 and history - B1. We could then change C's name and actual data will be A1, B2, C3 and history - B1, C1

Unfortunately, this requires to use `UNION ALL` in order to search records by criteria across the specific version:

```
select * from (
    select row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc) rn, 
           id, name, version 
    from 
    (
      select h.actual_id as id, h.name, h.version from history h
      union all
      select * from actual 
    ) x
    where version <= 2 
) y
where rn = 1 and name like '%something%';
```

This is obviosly a fullscan by `name` in `y` recordset (although both `actual` and `history` tables have indexes on `name` columns). And I cannot move `and name like '%something%'` into `where version <= 2` as it could find the name in the previous versions but not in the latest.

**How to optimize  this query? It is possible to tell postgres to use indexes in actual and history tables?**

Here below it the whole test case:

```
create table actual (id int, name text, version int);
create table history (id int, name text, version int, actual_id int);

insert into actual values (1, 'A', 3);
insert into actual values (2, 'B', 2);
insert into actual values (3, 'C', 2);
insert into actual values (4, 'D_changed', 5);

insert into history values (1, 'A', 1, 1);
insert into history values (2, 'B', 1, 2);
insert into history values (3, 'C', 1, 3);
insert into history values (4, 'D_old', 4, 4);
insert into history values (5, 'D_very_old', 2, 4);

select * from (
    select row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc) rn, 
           id, name, version 
    from 
    (
      select h.actual_id as id, h.name, h.version from history h
      union all
      select * from actual 
    ) x
    where version <= 5 -- and name like '%old%' - this finds wrong record ver=4
) y
where rn = 1 and name like '%old%';
```

Comment: Put your  `where version <= 5`  inside that UNION,no point in selecting all that data and then discarding it

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the query in the post. Unfortunately this does not fix the problem, the fullscan remains.

Comment: 1semi) `create table actual (id int, name text, version int)` there is a semicolon missing. 2NF) a table without a primary key (or unique constraint) has no meaning.

Comment: The tables have primary keys, and all columns are indexed. There also a foreign key from history to actual table. I skipped this here to reduce the code size. I think this is not important for the question as the fullscan occurs by `name` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the whole approach of using the version number is not a good idea. I managed to replace it to a more traditional way by adding `from_date` and `to_date` columns to the tables and the query became as simple as this:

```
select * from
(
  select h.actual_id as id, h.name, h.start_date, h.end_date from history h
  union all
  select * from actual 
) x
where ? between start_date and end_date
```